# Get values of IDENTITY values when inserting multiple rows into a table having instead of trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm inserting several rows into a table A which has an `instead of insert` trigger and an `identity` column.

Then I need to insert so many rows in a table B where each row hold a reference to the rows inserted in A.

The problem is, I can't use the `output` clause on A since, the identity will not be set (due to the trigger).

I know for one row I could use `@@identity` as long as the insertion of rows in A is the last insertion statement inside the trigger, but here I'm talking about multiple rows.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Friend had a similar problem, [I blogged about it here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current).

Comment: are you inserting in table A and table B in same proc ?i think you hv to use one temp table

Comment: I would suggest to create those Identities appropriately before hand and use those to insert in to the tableA and TableB.

Comment: this is very good question .It can be dome without temp table
i)Create View on table A and table B
ii)Create instead of trigger on view.
iii)here after insert into view passing all the value
iv)inside trigger write query to insert in TableA using output
v)Next statement inside trigger insert into TableB
Try and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I used code like this ( You CAN use table variable in OUTPUT clause )

```
declare @T table (requestID int); 
INSERT <tableA> (<fields>) 
       OUTPUT inserted.RequestID into @T 
VALUES( <fieldValues1> ),( <fieldValues2> ) ; 
Insert <tableB> (ID) select RequestID from @T;
```